# How do you code the perfect fuzzing function for some other function?

Tags: security, testing, fuzzing

Here is a snippet of code:

```
struct somedata {
    char mychar;
    int myint;
    unsigned short myushort;
    string mystring;
};

void some_func(somedata *data) {
  /* does something with data */
}
```

How do you write a *perfect* fuzzing function to test the correct functionality, security, and robustness of this code?

By perfect I mean complete tests that cover all cases (if possible). Say: out of range values, different data types, etc..

You do not have source code for `some_func`.

Comment: There is simply not enough information here to tell. We can start with the missing language — it looks like C or C++, but the `string` is puzzling; what is it a typedef of. You've not given any indication of the valid range for the integer columns; by default, therefore, you're looking at 2^56 combinations of possible values of the integers for each possible string value. You're not going to be able to do exhaustive testing, therefore. But without knowing more about what `some_func()` is supposed to do and what values are legitimate, it is going to be hard to find the correct boundaries. Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I got `fuzzing` wrong.

> **Fuzz testing** is a simple technique that can have a profound effect on
>   your code quality. In fuzzing we inject *random* bad data into an
>   application to see what breaks

Because `Fuzzing != Testing`, we do not build *perfect* test-cases or test all possible cases, instead we just generate random bad data and insert it into the application.

A Typical fuzzing function for the mentioned code would be:

```
void fuzzTesting ()
{
    //create somedata
    somedata data;

    //generate a random vector
    srand(time(NULL)); //seed = current_time

    //bufferOverflow
    int i= 200000
    while(i>=0)
    {
        r = rand()
        data.mychar = r;
        data.myint = r;
        data.myushort = r;
        some_func(&data);
        --i;
    }

    //Format String
    int i= 200000
    while(i>=0)
    {
        r = rand()
        data.mychar = '%s' + r;
        data.myint = '%s' + r;
        data.myushort = '%s' + r;
        some_func(&data);
        --i;
    }

    //Integer overflow
    int i= 200000
    while(i>=0)
    {
        r = rand()
        data.mychar = r + 0xffffffff;
        data.myint = r + 0xffffffff;
        data.myushort = r + 0xffffffff;
        some_func(&data);
        --i;
    }
}
```

for more fuzz testing vectors and details see this [wikipage](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fuzzing)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you might find interesting is using genetic fuzzers like [american fuzzy lop](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/) instead of writing the fuzz tests on your own. You would have to modify your program to operate on standard input and output (or on a file that is mentioned in the command line) and compile it with a special GCC/LLVM wrapper, but for exchange you would get a way to perform fuzzing with a tool that can learn your input/output format. It learns which bits induce new code paths when modified and gives them some extra attention. Also, have a look at LLVM's [LibFuzzer](http://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html), which uses a similar idea.